# Title of figure between the subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I make a figure with two subplots in the following way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig=plt.figure(1)
(ax1,ax2) = fig.subplots(2,1, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[1,15]})
```

the title appears between the subplots:

```
plt.title('Title')
plt.show()
```

How can I have the title on the top of the figure instead?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? Check here first. https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/figure_title.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [suptitle](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle.html) which places a centered title at the top of the figure.

**Using `plt.title`** (applies to the current axis which is `ax2` in your case)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig=plt.figure(1)
(ax1,ax2) = fig.subplots(2,1, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[1,15]})

plt.title('Title')
```

[image]

**Using `plt.suptitle`**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig=plt.figure(1)
(ax1,ax2) = fig.subplots(2,1, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[1,15]})

plt.suptitle('Title')
```

[image]

As suggested by [@ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) , you can also use `ax1.set_title('Title')` to put the title on the top because `ax1` corresponds to the top sub figure in your case.

Comment: Maybe worth mentionning that using `ax1.title('Title')` in the first case would also give the expected appearance.

Comment: Oh sure. Just give me few minutes. In a discussion currently. WIll update shortly

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest 
you are raising a point that is of interest for me. What is the general difference between `ax1` and `plt` ? Should I also use `ax1` instead of `plt` for ticks, labels and x and y range?

Comment: You find info on that be looking for the difference between "pyplot state-machine" and "object-oriented approach". In short `pyplot` (`plt`) will act on the "current figure" and "current axes", which is `ax2` in the case of the question. Hence that `ax2` will get the title when doing `plt.title("bla")`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: I added your suggestion. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I think it is `ax1.set_title('title')` rather than `ax1.title('title')`. I get an error otherwise.

Comment: Oh yes Sorry for the mistake

Comment: Ups, yes it's `set_title`. Sorry for being too quick in commenting.